# String prototype syntax for matching specific pattern in string

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I want to get the string position of the first character of `11-22` (`dd-dd`). 

The syntax of prototypes isn't clear to me yet, but I believe I'm close. 

For some reason, the code works now if I have `11 - 22` but without those spaces it doesn't work. 
Also, I want to exclude any matches that have more than two numbers on either side of the `-`.

I **don't** want to match `1111-2222`, only `11-22`.

```js
function myFunction() {
var str = 'For more information, 11-22 1111-2222';
var re = /\d+\d+\ +[-]+ \d+\d/i;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=(str.search(re));
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>result: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like the spaces are optional, you should quantify them with `*` (zero or more occurences). If you want exactly two digits, then use `\d\d` rather than quantify both digits with `+`, which doesn't make much sense when they're right next to each other:

```js
function myFunction(str) {
  console.log(str.search(/\b\d\d *- *\d\d/));
}
myFunction('For more information, 11-22 1111-2222');
myFunction('For more information, 11 - 22 1111-2222');
myFunction('foobar, 11 - 22 1111-2222');
myFunction('1111-2222 11 - 22');
```

Comment: But if the string order is 1111-2222 followed by 11-22, I get the wrong portion of the string (1111-2222 instead of 11-22). Can I use the * somewhere to indicate a space must precede \d\d?

Comment: Sure, just use a word boundary with `\b` - see edit. On newer browsers, you could also use lookbehind - `(?<= )` to indicate that a space comes right before

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly was a I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://regexr.com which has an interactive play pen where you can iterate your way to getting the regex you need.

(\D1{2}-2{2}\D)

is what I came up with which is close to, but not quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check position of **specific string** then you can do it with [`str.indexOf(your pattern)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) as well.

Check below code:

```js
function myFunction() {
var str = 'For more information, 11-22 1111-2222';
var re = "11-22";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=(str.indexOf(re));
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>result: <span id="result"></span></p>
```